# OpenCL: loop kernel?

Tags: c++, performance, queue, kernel, opencl

I'm running an OpenCL kernel that processes and re-processes the same data set over and over (it's an iterative physics solver).

In my tests, there is a non-trivial cost to calling clEnqueueNDRangeKernel. For example, when running 1000 substeps of the simulation (requiring 1000 identical calls to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel to process the same data), it seems that those calls to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel actually become the bottleneck. My (pseudo)code looks like this:

```
[create buffers]
[set kernel arguments]

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) //queuing the kernels takes a while
{
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, args...); 
}

clFinish(queue); //waiting for the queue to complete doesn't take much time
[read buffers]
```

I understand that the first call to clEnqeueuNDRangeKernel will initialize any deferred buffer transfers to the GPU...so the first call can have an additional cost. However, in my tests, a loop of 10 iterations is substantially faster than 1000 iterations, which leads me to believe the data transfer is not the bottleneck.

I'm also under the impression that clEnqueueNDRangeKernel is non-blocking in the sense that it won't block until the kernel is complete, so the complexity of the kernel shouldn't be the bottleneck (in my case, the kernel execution shouldn't block until the call to clFinish()).

However, when I profiled my code, the majority of time is spent merely processing the for loop, prior to the call to clFinish()...so it seems that the queuing of the kernels themselves is what's taking the most time here.

**My question**: is there a way to tell the GPU to re-run a previously-queued kernel N times, rather than having to manually queue a kernel N times? In my situation, no arguments for the kernel need to be changed or updated each iteration...the kernel just needs to be re-run. Can repeated calls to it be made more efficient?

Comment: Have you tried calling `clFlush()` every say 100 iterations to trigger kernel processing?

Comment: @doqtor Tried that just now...no discernable speed increase and the flush command apparently has it's own overhead which actually slowed things down further...

Comment: Since you aren't passing any new data or buffers have you tried doing the processing in 1 kernel in a loop instead of launching multiple kernels? Also as doqtor said try issuing in a bunch of 100 instances. But this time put an event in every 50th instance, then don't enqueue any further kernels. When the 50th instance finishes enqueue another hundred and so on. This helps avoid overfilling the buffer

Comment: @gallickgunner What do you mean by "doing the processing in 1 kernel in a loop"? Wouldn't I lose parallelism by doing that? I'm processing millions of elements so I need to maximize thread usage. I tried calling clFinish every few hundred calls (instead of clFlush as described above), and got no performance gain once again.

Comment: What i mean by processing in 1 kernel in a loop is that you just do your processing inside a for loop or something. You aren't gaining any parallellism this way either. The GPU can process 1 kernel at a time, the others are just queued. Profile the time taken by 1 kernel doing processing in a loop and your approach i.e instead of looping enqueue multiple times. Then see which is better

Comment: @gallickgunner Oh, I see what you mean. Unfortunately my kernels are dependent on previous results, so I can't simply move forward with another execution before the whole batch of kernel calls finish.

Comment: Yea then it's fine. How are you profiling btw? using opencl provided mechanism or C++ `chrono` header etc ?

Comment: @gallickgunner I'm using my own chrono-based profiler, measuring both inside and outside the OpenCL queue submission loops.

Comment: Hmm I don't think this should happen tho. How big of a time difference are we talking about? Also try measuring the execution time of 1 kernel, multiple it by 1000 and then measure the time taken by the above code. What's the time difference?

Comment: @Tyson _Unfortunately my kernels are dependent on previous results, so I can't simply move forward with another execution before the whole batch of kernel calls finish._ I think you are wrong here. Yes, you can move the whole loop inside the kernel, especially as you say you don't change kernel arguments each iteration. Do inside the kernel `for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){ <your current kernel content > }`.

Comment: @doqtor The kernel arguments don't change, but there are underlying buffers that are affected by the cumulative results of each successive kernel batch, so I can't do what you're suggesting (in my actual code I have sub-loop within my main enqueue loop that enqueues kernels based on previously generated data partitions...but I exploit the 'offset' parameter of the clEnqueueNDRangeKernel function so I don't have to pass new buffers to the kernels...I just queue non-overlapping groups of them with each sub-iteration....that's why I have to wait for all kernels to finish before I can continue).

Comment: @gallickgunner The time for 1 kernel (multiplied x 1000) and time for 1000 kernels are approximately the same, when adjusting the values based on the extra overhead of buffer transfer during the first kernel execution. I am going to experiment with enqueue_kernel to see if device-side queuing is faster.

Comment: I don't understand, if the both the time are coming same, then this would mean there is no bottleneck caused by calls to `enqueuekernel` since you know, kernel execution time doesn't take into account the time spent in those calls.

Comment: @gallickgunner The time I referred to is not kernel execution time. It's time to queue those kernels (sorry I should have specified...I'm talking about time *to queue* 1 kernel vs 1000). Calling clFinish after still blocks for a certain amount of time (roughly the amount of time I'd expect those kernels to take)....which means queuing the kernels has a non-trivial cost.

Comment: Note about clEnqueuNDRange being non-blocking. Only the dispatch is non-blocking. Unless you have out_of_order enabled, the *execution* of kernels is complete serialized.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL 2.x supports dynamic parallelism which lets 1 workitem launch new kernels. If each kernel launch doesn't need any gpu-cpu data transfer, you can have 1 workitem launch 1000 kernels and wait for each one to finish by that workitem. Use events to make all child kernels run after another.

In OpenCL 1.2, you could use atomics and a loop to do "in-flight threads" kernel synchronization but that wouldn't be faster than a new kernel launch imo and it is not a portable way of synchronizing them.

If each kernel launch costs more time than each kernel run, then there is not enough work done on GPU. You can simply do c=a+b on GPU and that won't be fast enough just because of kernel scheduling on gpu pipelines needing more time than doing c=a+b.

But, you can still do following approach using `clEnqueueWaitForEvents` and in-order command queues:

```
thread-0:
    enqueue user event, not triggered
    enqueue 1000 kernels, they don't start yet because of untriggered wait
thread-1:
    nothing
```

next time step:

```
thread-0:
    enqueue new user event on a new command queue, not triggered
    enqueue 1000 kernels on new command queue so they don't start yet
thread-1:
    run the old command queue from last timestep by triggering the user event
```

so that enqueueing and running can be "overlapped" at least. If you need more enqueue to run overlapping ratio,

```
thread-0 to thread-N-2:
    enqueue new user event on a new command queue, not triggered
    enqueue 1000 kernels on new command queue so they don't start yet
thread-N-1:
    iterate all command queues
          run currently selected command queue from last timestep  by triggering the user event
```

now that you have N-1 times faster enqueueing, running them would be only on GPU-side scheduling overhead. If you have GPU-side scheduling overhead much (1M workitems for 1M c=a+b calcs) then you should do more work per workitem.

Maybe making a producer-consumer style kernel launch is better where 7 threads produce filled command queues waiting to be triggered on their own user events and 8. thread consuming them by triggering them. This would work even if they need to upload download data to/from GPU.

Even old GPUs like HD7870 support 32+ command queues(per GPU) at the same time so you can scale enqueueing performane up by high-end CPUs.

If pci-e bridge(high latency by risers?) is causing bottleneck, then OpenCL2.x dynamic parallelism must be better than CPU-side producer-consumer pattern.

Comment: I like your host-threading idea, although I have a couple questions about enqueue_kernel since my device is OCL2.0 compatible: does a device-side enqueue utilize all workgroups, or just the workgroup of the queuing thread? Are there any other pitfalls I should be aware of when device-side queuing, or is doing it fairly straightforward and simple? Is it feasible to do device-side queuing when queuing millions of workitems, or is it better for smaller jobs? (In other words, is enqueue_kernel a close analogy to clEnqueueNDRangeKernel, or is it better for specific types of tasks only?)

Comment: Device-side enqueue can have a whole kernel launch. But they are generally advantageous when child kernels are very few workitems such that cpu could run them faster than enqueueing. Sometimes device-side enqueue increases device-side overheads depending on bugginess of drivers but still they are free of CPU-side overheads at least. You can use different synchronization flags in launching them from a workitem but I'd use events to make them run one after another at least to make sure. Device-side enqueueing needs some minor coding on host side too, for a different "main" command queue.

Comment: Millions of workitems shouldn't matter but thousands of kernel launches can get stuck on some buggy drivers because of limited resources allocated to that main queue. Yes, it is a nd launch where you give it its own array parameters and local/global ranges.

Comment: I mean in-kernel events, just like in-kernel kernel launches. https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/enqueue_kernel.html

Comment: Thanks for the extra info...I'll definitely give them a try and see if they can improve performance!

Comment: If you migrate to CUDA, there is graph feature that is reusable but didn't try.